# Prepared statement not working, resultset.next() has no records

Tags: java, oracle

Running below java code

```
final String Qry = QueryConstants.QUERY;
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            con = getDataSource().getConnection();
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(Qry);
            stmt.setString(1, abc1);
            stmt.setLong(2, abc2);          
            stmt.setString(3, abc3);
            long st = System.currentTimeMillis();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.error("RetrialDaoImpl.fetchFailedMessageFromDb:: time taken to fetch failed messages::" + (end - st) + "|likePattern::" + likePattern);
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("VERSION_NUMBER"));
            }
```

QUERY is below

```
SELECT MAX(VERSION_NUMBER) AS VERSION_NUMBER,  TLO_TYPE, TLO_ID 
FROM MSG_XML WHERE STATUS ='N' AND RECOVERABLE_FLAG ='Y' and PATTERN  =1 AND  ROWNUM <= 100 GROUP BY TLO_TYPE, TLO_ID) t1, MSG_XML x 
WHERE x.TLO_TYPE = t1.TLO_TYPE AND NVL(x.TLO_ID,1) = NVL(t1.TLO_ID,1) AND x.vdps_version_number = t1.vdps_version_number AND x.status  ='N' AND X.RECOVERABLE_FLAG ='Y' AND x.PATTERN = 1 ORDER BY X.RETRY_COUNT,  X.UPDATED_TIME
```

MSG_XML is a view. tried running the sql on sql developer it returns a record then why result set does not return anything.

Comment: How your query string which placeholders looks like?

Comment: And are the values of abc1,2,3 correct? or should that be the string?

Comment: @jens Query String is above in question and place holders are 1,100,1.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes all values are correct.

Comment: 1, 100,1 are no place holder. placeholder are question marks

Comment: as jens stated, replace the values with `?` and then you can set the values properly. with `stmt.setString...`

Comment: SELECT MAX(VERSION_NUMBER) AS VERSION_NUMBER,  TLO_TYPE, TLO_ID 
FROM MSG_XML WHERE STATUS ='N' AND RECOVERABLE_FLAG ='Y' and PATTERN  =? AND  ROWNUM <= ? GROUP BY TLO_TYPE, TLO_ID) t1, MSG_XML x 
WHERE x.TLO_TYPE = t1.TLO_TYPE AND NVL(x.TLO_ID,1) = NVL(t1.TLO_ID,1) AND x.vdps_version_number = t1.vdps_version_number AND x.status  ='N' AND X.RECOVERABLE_FLAG ='Y' AND x.PATTERN = ? ORDER BY X.RETRY_COUNT,  X.UPDATED_TIME

Comment: its already there.

Comment: PATTERN is of CHAR(3 BYTE) type and ROWNUM setting it by long.